# Vue JS when I click on button I want that the div scroll to bottom of the div

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, scroll

Hey I am making a chat bot but I want that when you press enter or click on button that the div scrolls to bottom, Because when you chat with the bot you need to scroll down ever time. I have a function but the scroll must be in the `talk()` function.

**This is the template code**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container max">
            <div class="container con">
                <div class="row ml-0 mt-3">
                    <p>{{this.know.welkom}}</p>
                </div>
               <p id="chatLog" class="chatLog font-weight-bold"></p><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col">
                <input id="userBox" class="inputChat" type="text" @keyup.enter="talk()" v-model="msg" required>
            </div>
            <div type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ml-2" @click="talk()">Send<img class="sendIcon" src="@/assets/icons/send.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**And this is my script**

```
import json from './info.json';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            title: 'Chat bot',
            test: this.json,
            know: {
                'welkom' : 'Welcome I will help you to answer your questions. If you want more info type "help".',
                'help' : 'These are the questions that can be answerd: <br>' + 
                         '1️⃣ how do you login <br>' +
                         '2️⃣ how do you register <br>' +
                         '3️⃣ how to add a internship <br>' +
                         '4️⃣ edit a internship <br>' +
                         '5️⃣ who are you',
                'how do you login' : 'If you are on the "Homepage" you see on the top a "Login" button click on it, ' + 
                                     'sign in with your email and password and you logged in.',
                'how do you register' : '1. Click on "login" on the navbar.' +
                                        '2. On the right side you see a "SIGN UP" button click on the button and you can register.',
                'how to add a internship' : '1. You need a account and you need to be logged in.' + '<br>' +
                                            '2. When you logged in you see above your email on the right side you see "Add internship" ' +
                                            'click on it.' + '<br>' +
                                            '3. Then you see some empty field you need to fill with your company information ' +
                                            '4. You can see how it is on the "Preview design" and if everthing is good click on "Add internship".',
                'edit a internship' : '1. Go to your "internship page". Their you see a edit button if you click on it you can edit ' +
                                      'your internship information.',
                'who are you' : 'I am your DAD! Look behind '
            },
            msg: ''
        }
    },
    head: {
        title: function () {
            return {
                inner: this.title
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        talk() {
            var user = this.msg;
            document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += user + '<br>';
            if (user != '') {
                if (user in this.know) {
                    document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += this.know[user] + "<br>" + "<br>";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += 'I don\'t understand...<br>' + '<br>';
                }
            } else {
                alert('Type text in');
            }
            this.msg = '';
            console.log(this.msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I used scrollheight between the `this.msg = '';` and  `console.log(this.msg);` see the `talk() function`

---

I added the scrollheight but it doesn't scroll automatically:

[image]

And this is the function code when I paste it:

```
talk() {
  var user = this.msg;
  document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += user + '<br>';
  if (user != '') {
     if (user in this.know) {
        document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += this.know[user] + "<br>" + "<br>";
     } else {
        document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML += 'I don\'t understand...<br>' + '<br>';
     }
     } else {
       alert('Type text in');
     }
     console.log(this.msg);
     this.msg = '';
     const chatLogDiv = document.getElementById('chatLog')
     chatLogDiv.scrollTop = chatLogDiv.scrollHeight
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to the bottom of the #chatLog div just do:

```
const chatLogDiv = document.getElementById('chatLog')
chatLogDiv.scrollTop = chatLogDiv.scrollHeight
```

Comment: It didn't scroll take a look on the picture and the code I added now.

Comment: It looks like your chatLog element is empty. Which element is meant to be scrolling? Add `ref="scroll"` to the element and select with `this.$refs.scroll`

Comment: This element must be scrolled: `class="container con"`

Comment: so change to: `const chatLogDiv = this.$refs.scroll` and add `ref="scroll"` to the element

Comment: Thanks it works! I put the `ref="scroll"` in the `class="container max"` element and now it scrolls to the bottom of the div.